# Abstract class with Swing Timer

Tags: java

I have an abstract class as follows:

```
abstract class Grapher implements Runnable{
  ... member variables...
  Timer timer;
  boolean Done;

   public void run(){
          Done = false;
          timer.start();
          while(!Done){}
   }

   public void Grapher(){ //create graph}
   ...
   }
```

The idea is that I want to have this abstract thread that creates a graph. I then want to extend this class to provide the implementation of what data that should be plotted on the graph. For example:

```
class RandomGraph extends Grapher{
   ActionListener taskPerformer;

   public RandomGraph(){
      timer = new Timer(1000, taskPerformer);
        taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
               // generate random data and add it to the graph data;
               // if ... Done = true
             }

         };
  }}
```

This should then plot random data to the graph. The problem I'm having is that I'm getting completely stuck in the `while(!done) loop`. Putting System.out.printlns inside the actionListener tell me the timer does not seem to be working as nothing appears on the console.

Am I being stupid for using threads at all? I thought it might be a good idea If I want the graph to plot data every few milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing `null` to the `Timer` constructor — you need to initialize `taskPerformer` first :-)

To address your bigger question: No, you're not stupid for using threads. However, I question your use of an abstract class at all here. What you really want is an *interface* `Grapher` describing an object that draws graphs, then a concrete subclass of `Runnable` (say, `GrapherRunner`) that sets up the timer, then delegates to a grapher to do the work.

(In OO-speak, this means using composition rather than inheritance.)

Comment: Ah, what a silly mistake. As it happens, It still doesn't seem to work. It is still getting stuck in the while loop. If I remove the while loop it works like it should. I think I will take your advice and try to rewrite this using an interface. I appreciate the help man, thank you :)

Comment: Ah, yeah, you'll need to make `Done` a volatile field (`volatile boolean Done;`) to use it to communicate between threads this way. Otherwise one thread can change it and the other thread will never know it changed.

Comment: What you *really* want, though, is something more like `Object.wait()` and `Object.notify()`: Replace `boolean Done;` with `Object doneLock;`, replace `while (!Done) {}` with `doneLock.wait()`; and replace `Done = true;` with `doneLock.notify()`. You can also have a look in the `java.util.concurrent` package for some helpful mechanisms; `CountDownLatch` does something like this.